# How does the current flow in the Hertz expermiment when reverse voltage is applied and the polarity of the electrodes is reversed?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, photons, photoelectric-effect

In the Hertz experiment, when light falls on the anode, electrons are emitted and they move towards the cathode and thus flow through the circuit.
However, when reverse voltage is applied and the polarity of the electrodes is reversed, electrons being emitted from the anode (formerly, a cathode) only come out in the air/vacuum of the glass tube and do not flow in the circuit even though voltage is applied.

How is it so? The emitted electrons should be repelled by the cathode and should enter the circuit through the wire attached to the anode as the increase in free electrons results in increase of current. The applied voltage should also direct the electrons to pass through the anode. In this way, a sort of capacitor might be created.

Instead, the current is said to reach zero as stopping potential is reached. How can this be justified?

Comment: Do you mean the [Franck-Hertz experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franck%E2%80%93Hertz_experiment)?

Comment: Yes @ThomasFritsch